# Hybris Populator. ClassNotFoundException "de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.convert.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator"

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

H! I wanted to create custom populator, and add to `defaultProductConfiguredPopulator`, but it throws exception

my custom-spring.xml

```
<bean id="defaultProductConfiguredPopulator" class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator">
    <property name="populators">
        <map key-type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.ProductOption">
            <entry key="PHYSICAL_DIMENSIONS" value-ref="customProductPopulator"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thrown exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAllDecorators' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator] for bean with name 'defaultProductConfiguredPopulator' defined in class path resource [customextension-spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

And my `Populator` class is simple:

```
public class CustomProductPopulator implements ConfigurablePopulator<ProductModel, ProductData, ProductOption> {
@Override
public void populate(final ProductModel source, final ProductData target, final Collection<ProductOption> options)
{
    target.setCode(source.getCode());
    if (options.contains(ProductOption.PHYSICAL_DIMENSIONS))
    {
        target.setWeight(source.getWeight());
        target.setHeight(source.getHeight());
    }
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator` belongs to the commercefacades extension, the class where you are trying to create your beans must depends on this extension.

But I would suggest a different approach. By doing

```
<bean id="defaultProductConfiguredPopulator" class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator">
    <property name="populators">
        <map key-type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.ProductOption">
            <entry key="PHYSICAL_DIMENSIONS" value-ref="customProductPopulator"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You are writing a new bean overdding the old one, maybe you should try

```
    <bean id="myCustomConfiguredPopulator" parent="defaultProductConfiguredPopulator">
    <property name="populators">
        <map key-type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.ProductOption" merge="true">
            <entry key="PHYSICAL_DIMENSIONS" value-ref="customProductPopulator"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or

```
<alias name="myCustomProductConfiguredPopulator" alias="productConfiguredPopulator"/>
<bean id="myCustomProductConfiguredPopulator" class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator">
    <property name="populators">
        <map key-type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.ProductOption">
        <entry key="PHYSICAL_DIMENSIONS" value-ref="customProductPopulator"/>
    </map>
</property>
```

Also, `de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator` is Deprecated since 6.0. Does it works if you use `de.hybris.platform.converters.impl.DefaultModifableConfigurablePopulator`?

Comment: Adding de.hybris.platform.converters.impl.DefaultModifableConfigurablePopulator instead of DefaultConfigurablePopulator helped, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bean configuration having issue and correct should be as below.

```
<bean id="defaultProductConfiguredPopulator"
        class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator">
```

Correction required in classpath of class for `defaultProductConfiguredPopulator`.

Comment: I have tried with this classpath many times before, it didn't work "de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.converter.impl.DefaultConfigurablePopulator". When I do global searching for entire project I couldn't find this class either.

Comment: search this bean `defaultProductConfiguredPopulator`, it's been used at multiple place in OOB spring file.

Comment: I haven't found this bean, unfortunately

Comment: then it's better to share your localextensions.xml in question as well